# What type of this sql query is this select from multiply table without join?

Tags: sql

The 3 table schema:

```
create table EMP
(ID char(9) not null primary key,
NAME varchar(20) not null,
AGE integer not null,
SALARY number not null,
constraint min_salary check (salary>30000));

create table DEPARTMENT
(DNUMBER integer not null primary key,
 DNAME varchar(15) not null unique,
 BUDGET float not null,
 MANAGER char(9) not null references EMP);

create table WORKS
(EMP char(9) not null references EMP,
DEPT integer not null references DEPARTMENT,
PCT_TIME integer,
constraint check_pct check (PCT_TIME between 0 and 100), constraint WORKS_PK PRIMARY KEY (EMP,DEPT));
```

What kind of query is this:

```
select name,age
from emp,department,works
where id=emp and dname='Software' and dept=dnumber
```

it select from 3 table but without a join keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that is called a cartesian product. It is defined as tables being linked without a limiting factor, such as a join statement.

Just confirmed it from here: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_sql_cartesian_product

Answer (score 3):

```
select name,age
from emp,department,works
where id=emp and dname='Software' and dept=dnumber
```

...would appear to be an implicit inner join query.  The `,` between the table are effectively doing a `CROSS JOIN`, returning the Cartesian Product, and the `where id=emp and dname='Software' and dept=dnumber` is effectively filtering the Cartesian product, producing the same effect as an `INNER JOIN`.  The criterion fields are not qualified with table names as they are not ambiguous.

Some database engines may not create as efficient a query plan for this type of join as they would for an explicit inner join query.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. you can select like:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1, Table2
```

which will do a full right outer join

If you want to make a left join, do this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE Table1.FID = Table2.ID
```

(where FID is the foreign id to the id in table 2).

So basically, your query is still a join query.

Comment: This explanation is utterly inaccurate in all its descriptions of joins.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Table1, Table2` is not a right join, it is a Cartesian product.  `SELECT * FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE Table1.FID = Table2.ID` is not a left join, it is a Cartesian product filtered to produce the same output as an inner join.  Left or Right joins have all records from the table on the Left or Right of the join statement and only those records from the other table that match the first on the join criteria.